# Azure Cosmos Db trigger function to locate which exact part of document is updated

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Document Db collection 'Coll_1' . I have also created a Azure cosmos db trigger function to check and take action whenever any document in 'Coll_1' is updated. However I need to know exact what part of the document is modified from the azure function. Please confirm if that is supported , else any solution for my issue is welcome please . My current function code is below :

```
    public static class CosmosDBTrigger
{
    [FunctionName("CosmosDBTrigger")]
    public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
        databaseName: "Coll1DB",
        collectionName: "Coll_1",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "DBConnection",
        LeaseCollectionName = "leases")]IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, TraceWriter log)
    {
        if (documents != null && documents.Count > 0)
        {
            log.Verbose("Documents modified " + documents.Count);
            log.Verbose("First document Id " + documents[0].Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment there is no way to identify which part of the document changed in the Change Feed. The Change Feed returns the state of the document after the update/insert operation.

You can vote for this feature in the [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/34177573-support-to-get-previous-version-in-change-feed) if it's a feature you'd like.